# Mixing local list operations with linq to entities database operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 lists. A shopping cart list, which contains a objects with the properties; `Quantity` and `ProductId`. I then get all products from the repository (`IQueryable`) that has `ProductId` in the shopping cart list. This means that for every product, there is a shopping cart object with the `Quantity` related to it.

When doing the select, I want to assign this `Quantity` also, but the only way I know to do this is to query the cart again.

For egx.

```
        model = (from p in productService.GetAllProducts()
                              where cart.Entries.Select(c => c.ProductId).Contains(p.ProductId)
                              select new CartViewItem
                                         {
                                             Price = p.Price,
                                             ProductId = p.ProductId,
                                             ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                             Quantity = cart.Entries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ProductId == p.ProductId).Quantity
                                         }).ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class ShoppingCartEntry
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

`cart.Entries` is not coming from a repository. `productService.GetAllProducts()` returns an entityframework's IQueryable.

**EDIT**: My new code is:

```
        model= (from p in productService.GetAllProducts()
                              from c in cart.Entries
                              where c.ProductId == p.ProductId
                              select new CartViewItem
                                         {
                                             Price = p.Price,
                                             ProductId = p.ProductId,
                                             ProductName = p.ProductName,
                                             Quantity = c.Quantity
                                         }).ToList();
```

This throws an error:
`Unable to create a constant value of type 'SampleApp.WebUI.Models.ShoppingCartEntry'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.`

Comment: Care to take a second stab at rewording your question?  I dont quite follow.  I was going to suggest using `let` but not sure yet if its the right fit.

Comment: Can you make the calculation based on all information that is retrieved?   Aka can you just make a property that automatically does it? Or is it aggregated?  The root of my question is really Why* do you want to put it in your select.

Comment: @Nix, I edited and I think its more clearer now. I like the automatic property thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this should work...

```
var model = (from c in cart.Entires  // The small local cart collection
             let cpid = cart.Entires.Select(c2 => c2.ProjectId) // 
             from p in productService.GetAllProducts() // Query all Products used in cart
                               .Where(queryp => cpid.Contains(queryp.ProjectId)).ToList()
             where p.ProductId == c.ProductId
             select new CartViewItem {
                 p.Price,
                 p.ProductId,
                 p.Brand,
                 p.ProductName,
                 Discount = p.DiscountPercent * c.Quantity}).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem with this `where-in` linq is that `cart.Entries` is not coming from a repository. productService.GetAllProducts() returns an entityframework IQueryable

Comment: This now gives: Unable to process the type 'SampleApp.WebUI.Models.ShoppingCartEntry[]', because it has no known mapping to the value layer.

Comment: GetAllProjects is Queryable and cart.Entries is a collection??

Comment: @Benjamin nope. Line 3 in your code throws the error thats at the bottom of my question. This is an entity framework specific problem?

Comment: this version? with let cpid? now check with sqlprofiler the generated query.

Comment: yes, how does that work? I'm trying to profile it to see if its 1 database call or it loops the calls.

Comment: this mix of memory collection and queryable is very tricky. From the most of all ORMappers only Contains will parsed in correct SQL. (WHERE IN (@p1, @p2, @p3.. all members of collection)).